# HTML5 + JavaScript To Flash?

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash, html

Im going to develop a Facebook app, and my client need that this app when shared the users can play in the fb wall, i know this is posible using the FB api and embeding a SWF file, this is not posible to achieve using HTML5 yet.

The question is, do you know about any tool to migrate from HTML5 canvas to Flash swf file?

Thanks beforehand, and If you have any idea or workarround please let me know.

Ps: yes ive searched online but ive just found Flash to HTML5 conversion tools, and as you could see i dont know flash so i dont know if a tool is really needed.

Comment: you've found flash to html5 conversion tools?? weird, I never found good tools to convert either way when I looked a few weeks ago. Even converters that *do* exist convert plain animation to and fro. Files with scripts are not handled well

Comment: i think you need to recode, rather than find a converter (if ever there is one that actually exists)

Comment: Well i found information that says that there are some... i dont know how efective the are

Comment: thats sad... :( ... any book you can suggest me? to learn enough flash and action script to code a simple canvas like game?

Comment: why flash of all things? stay with canvas and be happy

Comment: read the problem :( ... this can only be achieved with flash  as far as i know :(

Comment: @Joseph one cant put a javascript app directly on one's wall and share it like that , so unless you know how to do that in js this is the kind of case where you'd have to use flash. Why canvas all things when obviously there are cases where canvas doesnt work ? lol

Answer (score 1):

Check this one - http://code.google.com/p/flashcanvas/
I haven't used it yet but seems something helpful. It's for IE but with some tweaking around you should get it working.